# remove border-collapse style from ASP.NET DataList

Tags: asp.net, css, datalist

I'm a newbie at ASP.NET and am having trouble styling a DataList.  I've lately become enamored with rounded corners on borders and am trying to use the effect on all of my pages by applying it to all HTML tags.  On Internet Explorer, the border on my DataList looks terrible because I see [rounded corners around each element of my DataList](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7062/6862726281_b373f64b2b_o.png) rather than just the four corners of the outer box border.

I tracked this down to the fact that ASP.NET is adding:

```
style="collapse-border:collapse"
```

to the  tag that begins my DataList in the rendered HTML.  If this style rule is not present, the border looks [exactly as I intended](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7062/6862726321_4753e782e2_o.png).

I don't know how to eliminate the border-collapse style from what ASP.NET generates.  I don't see it present in the Visual Web Developer IDE or in the properties for the DataList.  I can't seem to override it in a style sheet either.  Does the style attribute on a tag trump all other rules?  Can anyone suggest how I can get ASP.NET to not generate the border-collapse style?

Comment: I haven't tried many browsers but I'm only having trouble with IE right now.  The border-collapse style doesn't bother Chrome.

Comment: Actually, the page does not look the way I want in other browsers when border-collapse:collapse is specified.  IE is maybe the worst looking but the others are not much better so that's even more reason for me to get rid of the style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `DataList` renders the `border-collapse: collapse;` style when its `CellSpacing` property is set to 0 (the default). To remove the style, set `CellSpacing` to `-1`.

Comment: Thanks, Michael!!!  That looks much better!!  I have an annoying gap between the content and the border but I hope I can figure that out with the proper style!

Comment: You're welcome! If you'd like, you can help other users see which answer was most helpful by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Checkmark done!  I'm new here and was trying to use the "up arrow".

Answer (score 0):

try setting borderstyle to none in design or

```
DataList1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
```